# How do you run python files with ! in filepath using vscode's integrated terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am running a python file in visual studio code 1.3.5.1 using an anaconda environment from a folder directory that contains !.

1. open file.py
2. right click
3. click "Run Python File in Terminal"

The (dummy) filepath looks

`/Volumes/Cake Pies/!Name/Bruce/!Jump/file.py`

I expect the python file to run in the integrated terminal, but instead get an error message in terminal. The exact error (with dummy data names):

```
(base) computer:pptx_auto Bruce$ source /Users/Bruce/anaconda3/bin/activate
(base) computer:pptx_auto Bruce$ conda activate pptx
(pptx) computer:pptx_auto Bruce$ /Users/Bruce/anaconda3/envs/pptx/bin/python "/Volumes/Cake Pies/!Name/Bruce/!Jump/file.py"
bash: !Name/Bruce: event not found
```

I understand that ! is a convention used in Unix shells, but don't know how to circumvent this problem.

Comment: [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is `#!`, not simply an exclamation. Furthermore, it's not a "Bash character;" it's a *convention* used by most shells in the Unix family. You need to correct the terminology in your question.

Comment: You also need to provide the *exact* error message, with the exception that you may replace included data specific to yourself with dummy data. Please do not expect readers to figure out exactly what error message you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback/clarification!

Comment: Have you tried escaping the "!" in the name? from the terminal try `"/Volumes/Cake Pies/\!Name/Bruce/\!Jump/file.py"`

Comment: Thanks, tbejos. In VS Code, the filename and path are sent to terminal automatically when you click "Run Python File in Terminal" from the context menu. It's this process I'm trying to troubleshoot. I believe escaping the ! works, but would involve manually inputting the commands to terminal. (I actually just dropped the ! from the filepath for my original use case, but am still curious if there is a way others have made this work.)